# Google plus share : image and description not coming

Tags: google-chrome-extension, subdomain, google-plus, basic-authentication, facebook-opengraph

I want to share link(from chrome extesnion) with image and description on Google plus.

It's working fine without **http basic authentication**.

i.e URL = "https://mysite.com"

But with **http basic authentication**, image and description doesn't load.

i.e URL = "https://subdomain.mysite.com"

For sharing I am using this:

In head secion:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My title"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://subdomain.mysite.com/my_logo.png"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="descption"/>
```

Sharing using link:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://subdomain.mysite.com/link" target="_blank">share</a>
```

What is the problem :

```
http-basic-authentication, subdomain or anything else ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was http-basic-authentication,
Solution of this problem : `skipped the http-basic-authentication` for particular controller(of shared url), below is the code :

```
def http_authenticate

  # this line resolved my problem 
  return if ["my_controller"].include? params[:controller]

  if Rails.env.staging?
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "u-name" && password == "pass"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried sharing URL using subdomain as shown, i did not see any problem, i was able to see description and logo.

[image]

#### Code used for replication.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name":"Share URL",
"description":"Share Some Trivial URL",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"browser_action":{
"default_popup":"popup.html"
}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl" target="_blank">share</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just fiddle it but it just shows the Hyperlink share.. @ SudarShan